Usar Extends DatabaseNotification en Laravel y Filament
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto laravel con Filament y tenant (El tenant de filament propio), una de las cosas que estoy trabajando ahora son los exportAction para descargar documentos excel y recibir la notification del tipo ->databaseNotifications() como es un sistema tenant la logica cambia un poco, pero no logro hacer que la configuracion que he aplicado me funcione.
a la migracion le he agregado customer_id que seria la relacion con el cliente logeado
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->default(1);
            $table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('notifications');
    }
};

luego averiguando me recomendaron extender mi modelo Notification (Modelo propio creado para mi proyecto, no es hago referencia al que trae Laravel) a DatabaseNotification, y lo tengo asi:
<?php

namespace App\Models\Company;

use App\Models\Company;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Models\Contracts\HasTenants;
use Filament\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
use Filament\Panel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Notification extends DatabaseNotification implements HasTenants
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    // Indica que el ID no es un entero sino un UUID
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable = [
        'customer_id',
        'type',
        'data',
        'read_at',
        'notifiable_id',
        'notifiable_type'
    ];

    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        self::addGlobalScope('for_logged_company', function(Builder $builder):void {
            if (auth()->guard('company')->check()) {
                $user = auth()->user(); // Obtiene el usuario logeado
                $companies = $user->companies; // Obtiene la relación "companies" del usuario
                if ($companies->count() > 0) {
                    $company = $companies->first(); // Suponiendo que un usuario solo pertenezca a una empresa
                    $companyId = $company->id; // Obtiene el ID de la empresa
                }
            }
        });
        /* Se guardara automaticamente el Customer_id en la tabla, obtenido del usuario logeado, esto permite que no tengamos que pedirlo en el resource */
        self::saving(function (self $company): void {
            if (auth()->guard('company')->check()) {
                $user = auth()->user(); // Obtener el usuario logeado
                //dd($user);
                $companies = $user->companies; // Obtener las compañías relacionadas con el usuarioveamos
                if ($companies->count() > 0) {
                    $company = $companies->first(); // Suponemos que el usuario pertenece a una sola compañía
                    $company->company_id = $company->id; // Asignar el ID de la compañía al modelo de routine
                }
            }
        });

        // Asignar automáticamente el `customer_id` basado en el tenant logeado
        self::creating(function (self $notification) {
            // Obtén el tenant actual
            if ($tenant = Filament::getTenant()) {
                $notification->customer_id = $tenant->id;  // Asigna el ID del tenant como customer_id
            }
        });
    }

    public function companies(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }

    public function getTenants(Panel $panel): array|Collection
    {
        return $this->companies;
    }

    public function canAccessTenant(Model $tenant): bool
    {
        return $this->companies->contains($tenant);
    }
}

aca en el self::creating se supone que al guardar me deberia guardar ese customer_id
en la columna de la tabla pero no paso nada. Claro analizando es logico ya que no lo llamo en ningun lado para aplicar este cambio.
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Exports\Company;

use App\Models\Company\CommonArea;
use Filament\Actions\Exports\ExportColumn;
use Filament\Actions\Exports\Exporter;
use Filament\Actions\Exports\Models\Export;

class CommonAreaExporter extends Exporter
{
    protected static ?string $model = CommonArea::class;

    public static function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            ExportColumn::make('id')
                ->label('ID'),
            ExportColumn::make('nombre'),
            ExportColumn::make('description'),
            ExportColumn::make('valor'),
            ExportColumn::make('rangeuntil'),
            ExportColumn::make('availabledays'),
            ExportColumn::make('disponibilidad'),
            ExportColumn::make('companies.name'),
            ExportColumn::make('created_at'),
            ExportColumn::make('updated_at'),
        ];
    }

    public static function getCompletedNotificationBody(Export $export): string
    {
        $body = 'Your common area export has completed and ' . number_format($export->successful_rows) . ' ' . str('row')->plural($export->successful_rows) . ' exported.';

        if ($failedRowsCount = $export->getFailedRowsCount()) {
            $body .= ' ' . number_format($failedRowsCount) . ' ' . str('row')->plural($failedRowsCount) . ' failed to export.';
        }

        return $body;
    }
}

y luego tengo en mi Resource el boton para generar el archivo
Tables\Actions\ExportAction::make()
  ->exporter(CommonAreaExporter::class)
  ->after(function () {
    $tenant = Filament::getTenant();
    // Crear una notificación utilizando tu modelo Notification
    \App\Models\Company\Notification::create([
    'type' => 'export_completed',
    'notifiable_id' => $tenant->id, // ID del tenant
    'notifiable_type' => 'App\Models\Customer', // Tipo del modelo notifiable
    'data' => json_encode(['message' => 'La exportación ha sido completada']),
    'customer_id' => $tenant->id, // Asegúrate de asignar customer_id correctamente
  ]);
})

Hasta aca el excel se crea bien, pero lo que no se esta creando es la notificacion en la tabla, ya que la notificacion es la que me devuelve el link para descargar el excel, mi problema es que no entiendo bien como hacer el llamado para estos casos... la idea seria llamar al modelo y que se cree la notificacion, pero obtengo como respuesta este error!
Call to undefined method App\Models\Company\Notification::create()
Que o de que forma puedo guardar esta notificacion en la tabla?
